# Uibutton font alignment issue when using font property on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem when setting a uibutton property:

```
[self.btnName.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"gillsansstd" size:16.0]];
```

It will disturb the text alignment, text shows top of button.
Why does setFont disturb the text alignment of uibutton?

Comment: where you set alignment?

Comment: i set alignment through .Xib file

Answer (score 0):

Following Code set center (horizontally) of Alignment of `UIButton`  titile  .

```
myButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
```

**Other Way**

```
[myButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

Comment: I can do this in in .Xib but no effect :(

Comment: thanks for your response. when i use custom font for UIbutton it will effect the title text alignment and when i use System fonts the button title position remains perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need.

```
[btnName.titleLabel setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
```

You can vertically align the text in a button.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Edge Inset from xib file.

[image]

[image]